# Oracle Function-based index doesn't work except in a inline view

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

We are finding a really strange issue in Oracle 11g (11.2.0.3.0)

There is a function based index created on the `transactions` table that does not work unless it's in an inline view. The index is declared on `TO_CHAR(whenmodified, 'yyyy-mm-dd')`

This first query never ends:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(tran.whenmodified, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
FROM transactions tran
WHERE TO_CHAR(tran.whenmodified, 'yyyy-mm-dd') = '2014-05-09'
    AND rownum < 10;
```

This other query works perfectly:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(tran.whenmodified, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
FROM (SELECT * FROM transactions ) tran
WHERE TO_CHAR(TRAN.WHENMODIFIED, 'yyyy-mm-dd') = '2014-05-09'
    AND rownum < 10;
```

The execution plan is exactly the same for both and it uses the index in both cases.
Can anyone think of anything that may cause this issue?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why are you using a function-based index at all? It would make more sense to convert your string to a date and select on date... If you don't want a time based element construct an index on `trunc(whenmodified)` instead and query on `where trunc(whenmodified) = date '2014-05-05'`. It's more logical to query a date as a date...

Comment: We thought on that option too. When a record is created on TRANSACTIONS, the whenmodified column is set. It's also updated several times after the transaction gets processed, sent, validated by an user, etc.
So the index would have to be updated several times for each record and it probably would make a big impact.
But we haven't tried the option of creating a function based index on TRUNC(whenmodified) to query as a date as you suggest